# What song am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, music

> The waters, the sea
>   My pillow in my bed
>   The waters, the sea
>   I dreamt that they were dead
>
> Fetch me, and return
>   As winds blow o'er the same
>   Fetch me, and return
>   My body or my dame

What song am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ths one

> [My_Bonnie_Lies_over_the_Ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Bonnie_Lies_over_the_Ocean)

I guess it's about what you know... it took me 5 seconds, but I have it on LP here somewhere, so 5 seconds today, and hours of training many years ago,

Explanation:
the clues are simpliifications, or reinterpretations of the song lyrics.

```
The waters, the sea
```

verse 1:

> My Bonnie lies over the ocean
>  My Bonnie lies over the sea
>  My Bonnie lies over the ocean
>  Oh, bring back my Bonnie to me...

```
My pillow in my bed
I dreamt that they were dead
```

verse 2

> Last night as I lay on my pillow
> Last night as I lay on my bed
>  Last night as I lay on my pillow
>  I dreamt that my Bonnie was dead

```
 Fetch me, and return
 As winds blow o'er the same
 Fetch me, and return
```

Chorsue:

> Bring back, bring back
>  Oh, bring back my Bonnie to me, to me
>  Bring back, bring back
>  Oh, bring back my Bonnie to me

also verse 3:

> Oh, blow the winds o'er the ocean
>  And blow the winds o'er the sea
>  Oh, blow the winds o'er the ocean
>  And bring back my Bonnie to me

```
 My body or my dame
```

I can't explain that clue - perhaps some different arrangement of this song.

Comment: Correct! You want to provide your interpretation of the clues, for those who don't know? Thanks.

Comment: And what's "LP"?

Comment: Vinyl Record: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LP_record

Comment: if you they lyrics (linked) they prett-much parallel the clues, except for the last line... maybe some other variant of the song.

Comment: The last clue is in reference to a [commonly misheard lyric](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qa89XRQr-R0).